# Proof by Induction on Recursive Sequence - MCT

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification, induction

> Let $a_{n+1}$ = $4 + 2a_n^{\frac{1}{3}}$, where $a_1$ = $1$
> $i)$ Prove that $1 \leq a_n \leq 8$.
> $ii)$ Prove that $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \geq 1$ for all natural numbers $n$.

**My attempt:**

$i)$

Base case $n=1$: $a_1$ = 1, which is greater than or equal to $1$ and less than or equal to $8$, so true for $n=1$.

Assume the statement holds for some natural number $k$: $1 \leq a_k \leq 8$, where $n=k$.

Now try for $n=k+1$. $a_{k+1} = 4 + 2a_k^{\frac{1}{3}}$. By assumption, $a_k \geq 1$, so $a_{k+1} \geq 4 + 2 \cdot 1 = 6 > 1$, so $a_{k+1} \geq 1$.

Also note that by assumption $a_k \leq 8$, so $a_{k+1} \leq 4 + 2\cdot 2 = 8 \leq 8$.

Hence, statement is true by mathematical induction.

$ii)$

Base case $n=1$. $\frac{a_2}{a_1} = 6 \geq 1$, so true for $n=1$.

Assume the statement holds for some natural number $k$. $\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k} \geq 1$, where $n=k$.

Now try for $n=k+1$. $a_{k+2} = 4 + 2a_{k+1}^{\frac{1}{3}}$. $a_{k+1} = 4 + 2a_{k}^{\frac{1}{3}}$.

Notice that $\frac{a_{k+2}}{a_{k+1}}$ = $\frac{4 + 2a_{k+1}^{\frac{1}{3}}}{4 + 2a_{k}^{\frac{1}{3}}}$.

Now I don't know how to proceed from the inductive step. Could I have some help on completing part $ii$ but also verifying that I am fine for part $i$. Thanks : )

Comment: For (ii), we only need to prove $4+2\sqrt[3]{a_n}\geq a_n$. Hint: The result from (i) should be helpful. In this way, for (ii) we don't need to use induction. Another hint: $x^3-2x-4=(x-2)(x^2+2x+2)$.

Comment: The $a_{n}$ they are not negative, you showed that in $(i)$. Now, by hypothesis of induction you have $a_{k+1}\geqslant a_{k}$ then $4+2a_{k+1}^{1/3}\geqslant 4+2a_{k}^{1/3}$ and notice that $a_{k+2}=4+2a_{k+1}^{1/3}$ and $a_{k+1}=4+2a_{k}^{1/3}$.

Comment: @user1027216 Okay, would I then divide both sides by $a_{k+1}$ to show that the fraction is $\geq 1$? Was my first proof okay and set out correctly ?

Comment: @NikitaMazepin Well, the $a_{n}$ they are not negative, so $\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_{k}}\geqslant 1$ is logically equivalent to $a_{k+1}\geqslant a_{k}$.

Comment: @user1027216 Okay, they confused my because of the quotient, I normally prove these things like in the final inequality you posted in your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The base case and the inductive step in $(i)$ seems correct for me.
- The base case in $(ii)$ it is correct. For the inductive step we have by hypothesis of induction that $\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_{k}}\geqslant 1$ for some $k\in \mathbf{N}$. By $(i)$ the $a_{k}$ is not negative so $\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_{k}}\geqslant 1$ is logically equivalent to $a_{k+1}\geqslant a_{k}$ and applying the increasing mapping $k\mapsto k^{1/3}$ both sides of inequality give $a_{k+1}^{1/3}\geqslant a_{k}^{1/3}$ and then $2a_{k+1}^{1/3}\geqslant 2a_{k+1}^{1/3}$ and then $\color{blue}{4+2a_{k+1}^{1/3}\geqslant 4+2a_{k}^{1/3}}$ for some $k\in \mathbf{N}$. Finally, we have
  $$\frac{a_{k+2}}{a_{k+1}}=\frac{\color{blue}{4+2a_{k+1}^{1/3}}}{4+2a_{k}^{1/3}}\color{blue}{\geqslant }\frac{\color{blue}{4+2a_{k}^{1/3}}}{4+2a_{k}^{1/3}}=1.$$
  Hence the inductive step it is true, and the result follows.